# How to change the focus of an HTML input element in Javascript

Tags: javascript, focus

I have an input bar. I'd like to change the color of that input bar when someone clicks on it, but I want to do it in Javascript. How would I do this?

Comment: So add a focus event....

Comment: Is there any way I can do that in pure Vanilla JS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_onfocus

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

Enter your name: <input type="text" onfocus="myFunction(this)" id="abc" onblur="blured()">

<p>When the input field gets focus, a function is triggered which changes the background-color.</p>

<script>
function myFunction(x) {
  x.style.background = "yellow";
}

function blured(x) { 
 document.getElementById('abc').style.background = "white";
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

You can add a blur event (is the inverse of focus)

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/blur_event

Comment: Could this be done so that when I click away from the input bar, the focus goes away?

Answer (score 0):

This will change the background color of the input with plain JavaScript and no CSS.

```
<input type="text">
<input type="text">
<input type="text">

<script>
  var inp = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
  for(var i = 0; i < inp.length; i++){
    inp[i].addEventListener('focus', function(){
      this.style.background = "red"
    }.bind(inp[i]))

    inp[i].addEventListener('blur', function(){
      this.style.background = "none"
    }.bind(inp[i]))
  }
</script>
```

It loops through each **input** element, adds two event listeners, one for when it has "focus" and one for when it loses focus ("blur"), which fire on those events and styles them.

Comment: This is basically what I want, but I need the background-color to be changed in javascript, not CSS. Could that be done?

Comment: Yes, I modified the code so that it does this. The **.focus()** method was no longer needed.